# PHP Interpreter

Tags: php, netbeans, zend-framework2, interpreter

I have installed **Netbeans 8.0** and I think he installed with php because I haven't made others installation and everything work, but now I try to make Zend Framework 2 work and I have downloaded the skeleton select it, select the composer but because it can't detect php interpreter it can't run the composer and gives an error when use zend classes.

My question is where I can find the interpreter because I look in netbeans/php and I haven't find a php.exe and also I haven't find it anywhere my pc.

Comment: Why don't you install it manually

Comment: You have to install php manually depending on your operating system and then select the php executable (depending where you have located the php binaries).

Comment: Is there a install that do all the work?Because I saw that you have to do a lot of configuration and I don't want to mess anything.

Comment: And also I can't understand how can it be not install if I made a lot of application until now and it works.

Comment: There are packages, but I hardly NOT suggest using them. Better take hour or two to understand how to configure PHP on your computer, and then install it.

Comment: But you see the problem is that is not my own computer,is the computer from work and I am connect to a server, there is a posibility that PHP is on server and I use it from there?

Comment: I thought that netbeans do all the work with mysql and php since I only install it and everything work but now I think maybe the server did all the work because it has everything install there?

Comment: Well, if the files are on remote server, ofcourse it uses the PHP installed there

Comment: An in this situation what php interpreter I select in netbeans?

Comment: Not sure it's possible, but there was possibility where you can specify it's a remote app

Comment: But you will lose a lot of the benefits that way, better checkout the project on your local computer, install php and tell netbeans to use your php interpreter and work on local

Comment: And if I tell netbeans to use the local php not the server php will change anything else than using that php to interpret php code?

Comment: And also how I install php local and use the remote server?Because I don't want to install another server,I want to use the firm server and has to be possible because everyone use Zend 2 and everyone is conected tho the same server and I don't think they had to install php,mysql and webserver local to use it

Comment: No, you develop on your local then deploy on the central server and everyone is using the central... no offense, but how do anyone has given you access to his central server, when you even don't know how to install php

Comment: I start to learn php,mysql,html,javascript from  0 a month ago and I used wamp at home,and at firm I only installed netbeans and use the firm server,they onli give me a acces to my own folder so I can see in browser what I code,I am an intern here and thats why,but now was my first time try to make Zend project and that's why I didn't know from where to take the php.exe because I never needed it before,until now I just make small application in netbeans to learn and get uset to php,mysql,htmll,css and javascript.

Comment: And just know I finished to put basic on those and move to learn more about server-client,mvc and zend.Now you understand?Aniway I manage to do it by install wamp and use only the php.exe from wamp to run composer and  I keep using the company server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use software like XAMPP, LAMP (both available also for linux), WAMP. All off them contain PHP. Windows packages have pretty installers.